# Is it possible to have a global exception catch akin to a few php frameworks(Yii2) in android

Tags: android, exception

I would like to know if I can write a global catch statement, whose messages I can then show in a single `Snackbar.make` statement.

Comment: You can set a default uncaught exception handler, using methods on `Thread`. However, you will not be able to show a `Snackbar` directly, as you do not have access to any activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare what about toast? they work with application contexts yes?

Comment: Yes, you can show a `Toast`. However, rather than rolling your own implementation of this, I recommend that you consider using [ACRA](http://acra.ch/), which already handles a lot of the complexity of creating crash handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the help!